# JSON schema to JSON data

Tags: json, jsonschema

I wanted to create `JSON` data from `JSON schema` in `JavaScript`.

I tried using `JSON schema fakers`, But the problem is it validates and generates random data all time, Sometimes I don't get all keys.

for example(Sample `JSON schema`)

```
{
"$schema" : "http://schema.net",
"id" : "0",
"definitions" : 
{
"cote" : 
{
"type" : "string"
}
}
}
```

The data generated by `JSON Schema faker` is `{}`. As you can see not all keys are generated here. But I want all keys to be there. So is there any way I can create `JSON` data from Schema which contains all keys. Also,If there any way I can add `required:[]` to schema, I can use `Schema faker` to generate data.

How will I approach the problem in `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0):

is very similar

```
var data = {
    schema : "http://schema.net",
    id : "0",
    definitions :{
        cote :{
            type : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But  I wanted like this. var data={ "cote" : "hello" }.

Comment: I need JSON data

Comment: Ok is easy 'var obj = JSON.parse(text);' or var obj = JSON.parse('string');